# VueJS - Giving refs on this.$refs a type to remove Typescript errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In rough pseudo code, if I do something like this:

```
<v-menu
  ref="dmenu"
  other="stuff here"
  @change="save"
>
```

And then reference it later:

```
save(val: string) {
  this.$refs.dmenu.save(val)
}
```

I get an error "Property 'save' does not exist on type 'Element'"

Is it possible to declare that items on `this.$refs.` are of type any?

This works:

```
save(val) {
  const m = this.$refs.dmenu as any
  m.save(val)
}
```

But it seems like an extra line of code just to keep Typescript happy.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/94

Comment: @StephenThomas thanks for the link. Most of the suggestions belong to older versions, but even the recent ones give me an error. I'll play around a bit more tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either specify the type of element as **VMenu** and then access the method on it otherwise you have to specify the marked ref as any.

```
(this.$refs.dmenu as any).save(val)
```

Comment: I think that using the actual type would be more elegant, no? Here is an article with examples: http://lpains.net/articles/2019/tips-tricks-typescript-vue/